# Java public static boolean method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I want to make a little program which will ask for two numbers first, checks whether they are good or not using a method, and then, after having the last number, prints out the result of the method. (yes you win, no you lose).

I compared this with other questions on here, but somehow I can't get it to work. I made the luckyNumbers inside the method, outside the method, even bought "Big Java" but I'm stuck on this now.

Help would be very appreciated!

```
package wtf;

import Java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Darl
 */
public class WTF {
public static int luckyNumber;
public static int secondLuckyNumber;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give me a number between 0 and 100 to win a prize. ");
    luckyNumber = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Give me another number between 100 and 200.");
    secondLuckyNumber = sc.nextInt();

}

public static boolean hasLuckyNumber(int luckyNumber, int min, int max){
    min = 20; //all winning tickets from 20 till 60
    max = 60;
    if (luckyNumber > min || luckyNumber < max) {
        System.out.println("Unfortunatly, no prize");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You've got a prize!");
    }
}

public static boolean hasSecondLuckyNumber(int secondLuckyNumber, int min, int max){
    min = 140; // all winning tickets from 140 till 175
    max = 175;
    if (secondLuckyNumber > min || secondLuckyNumber < max){
        System.out.println("Sad face");
    }else{
        System.out.println("We've got a winner!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: Note that buying a book doesn't just give you knowledge. What do you think your program is doing? Why can't you get it to do what you want?

Comment: *I can't get it to work* -- What is your program supposed to do?  What does it actually do?  What errors (if any) do you get when you run it?

Comment: You're not calling either of those functions in your main - is that what you're stuck with?

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all you don't return anything from your methods. You can either change the return value of the functions to void since you print the result inside the function, or make the printing in the main, based on the return value.

Second, you don't call the methods anywhere in the code, so nothing will happen.

*notice that there is no need in the min/max parameters if you initialize them inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

For the Methods hasLuckyNumber(...) and hasSecondLuckyNumber(...) you have to return a boolean value, either true or false. Then inside main you have to change your implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Give me a number between 0 and 100 to win a prize. ");
  luckyNumber = sc.nextInt();

  if(hasLuckyNumber(luckyNumber)) {
      System.out.println("Give me another number between 100 and 200.");
      secondLuckyNumber = sc.nextInt();

      if(hasSecondLuckyNumber(secondLuckyNumber)) {
        System.out.println("We've got a winner!");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Sad face");
      }
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Unfortunatly, no prize");
  }

}

public static boolean hasSecondLuckyNumber(int secondLuckyNumber){
    if (secondLuckyNumber > 140 || secondLuckyNumber < 175){
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}

public static boolean hasLuckyNumber(int luckyNumber){
    if (luckyNumber > 20 && luckyNumber < 60) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are having (amongst other things i.e. boolean methods not returning boolean values etc..) is this:

```
(luckyNumber > min || luckyNumber < max)
```

should be this:

```
(luckyNumber > min && luckyNumber < max)
```

Also the same for:

```
secondLuckyNumber > min || secondLuckyNumber < max
```

Should be:

```
secondLuckyNumber > min && secondLuckyNumber < max
```

With an `||` a value greater than max would return true because the first statement `luckynumber > min` would return true. Replacing this with an `&&` will only return true if the `luckynumber` is more than `min` and less than `max`

Answer (score 0):

are you getting compile errors because you're not returning the boolean from your methods?

```
public static boolean hasSecondLuckyNumber(int secondLuckyNumber, int min, int max){
    min = 140; // all winning tickets from 140 till 175
    max = 175;
    if (secondLuckyNumber > min || secondLuckyNumber < max){
        System.out.println("Sad face");
        return false;
    }else{
        System.out.println("We've got a winner!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

maybe?
looks like you don't need the boolean, since you're using the console to write out if you win or lose though.